# How to effectively validate kafka listener payloads

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

What is the effective way to validate kafka listener paylods?

Currently, once the event is received inside the listener method we are validating the payload for any required attributes. Can this be done befor entering the listener method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; see the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafka-validation

```java
@KafkaListener(id="validated", topics = "annotated35", errorHandler = "validationErrorHandler",
      containerFactory = "kafkaJsonListenerContainerFactory")
public void validatedListener(@Payload @Valid ValidatedClass val) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: But the ValidatedClass in my scenario is an avro generated class, not sure how can we add validator to those auto generated classes. And also can we have validator for each listener or is this specific to a listenercontainerfactory

Comment: You don't "add it to the class" you would create a validator to validate the instance after it is created by avro. Currently it's one validator per factory; you can use a different factory for each listener or create a validator that delegates to different ones depending on the type. We could add an override to `@RabbitListener(... validator="myValidator")` to override the validator in the factory. Feel free to open a new feature request on GitHub.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell I'd like to validate an Avro generated class's content as well.  Can you point to an example of where a validator is specified on a container factory?  I'm not finding any examples.  Thanks!

Comment: I think I found an example of yours - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/816#issuecomment-426020131

Answer (score 0):

Configure Kafka listeners to know the validation bean validation

```java
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class Config implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;
    ...

    @Override
    public void configureKafkaListeners(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setValidator(this.validator);
    }
}
```

Set your validations:

```java
public static class ValidatedClass {

  @Max(10)
  private int bar;

  ...

}
```

Add @Valid next to @Payload of the method that is using @KafkaListener

```java
@KafkaListener(id="bar", topics = "bar")
public void validatedListener(@Payload @Valid ValidatedClass val) {
    ...
}
```

the same as described in the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/receiving-messages/validation.html